# Invalid Callback Error when Setting Up Mocked Method using Moq

Tags: mocking, moq

I have a class that I am testing.  This class has a dependency that I am mocking with the latest version of Moq.  The method I am mocking has the following signature.

```
IQueryable<T> Get<T>(
      Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
      Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
      string property = "")
      where T : BaseEntity;
```

I mock this in this way

```
_repositoryMock
                .Setup(_ => _.Get(
                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<X, bool>>>(),
                    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<X>, IOrderedQueryable<X>>>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns<X>(_ => Enumerable.Empty<X>().AsQueryable());
```

When I run this test, I get the following error for this line.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid callback. Setup on method with 3 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of parameters (1).'
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Returns` statement to

```
.Returns(Enumerable.Empty<X>().AsQueryable());
```

If you want to provide a delegate you've got to provide all of the parameters.